# React, Axios issue: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status ( 404 not found )

Tags: authentication, axios, basic-authentication

I've been trying using axios with basic auth but it always returns not found.

**Here is my code**

```
const ROOT_URL='http://localhost/b2b_ecom/b2b-api/index.php/api/';

export function login () {


    return function(dispatch)
    {

        const api = axios.create({
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials:'include',
            redirect: 'follow',
            auth: {
                username: 'mouad@b2b.dz',
                password: '123456'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        });

        api.post(`${ROOT_URL}site/login `).then(function(response)
        {
            dispatch({LOGIN,payload:response.data});
            return true;

        }).catch(function(error)
        {
            return error;
        });

    } ;

}
```

And here it is the error I got:

> OPTIONS http://localhost/b2b_ecom/b2b-api/index.php/api/site/login 404 (Not Found)
>   Failed to load http://localhost/b2b_ecom/b2b-api/index.php/api/site/login: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFZwi.png)

Comment: 404 means your PHP server can't find a resource at `http://localhost/b2b_ecom/b2b-api/index.php/api/site/login` There's really nothing we can do to fix this. You need to check that the URL is correct.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with JavaScript; (if there's no typo in URL) you should describe which server do you use and how its routing is configured. Please also add appropriate tags to your question

Comment: Actually, I was using a Google chrome CROS extension. When I disable it the error changes:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.

P.S: yes it is working properly with postman

Answer (score 0):

I think browser is adding access control header to request. 
Check the following things

1) When you hit from postman or other such api clients this api should be working properly. (even curl is fine)

2) Try adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin as * for this request on server and see if it works.

Comment: Actually, I was using a Google chrome CROS extension. When I disable it the error changes:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.

P.S: yes it is working properly with postman